# Why can't I use another Finished() value instead of calling .next_scene() in LPTHW Ex 43?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The complete code is here http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

My main question is the part of code below:

```
class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        current_scene.enter()
```

I am confused at why can't I replace `self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')` with `Finished()` like this way:

```
last_scene = Finished()
```

When I replace it, the while-loop never terminates?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest** code necessary to **reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Scene` baseclass doesn't define a custom equality test, so `current_scene != last_scene` falls back to a default: testing if two references point to one and the same object, instead.

You created a *new* `Finished()` instance, and it will *always* be un-equal to every other `Finished()` instance, including what `self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)` returns:

```
>>> Finished() != Finished()
True
```

---

I must note that I **strongly** recommend against using *Learn Python the Hard Way* to learn Python. It only teaches Python 2, which is now a legacy version of the language in maintenance mode for only a few years more, and there are [a long list of other issues](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints).

You'd be much better of picking up a book that teaches Python 3, instead. See [these alternatives](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).